Image segmentation for a massive number of distinct objects
Relatively new to ML/CV and trying to solve an image processing task that doesn't fit the more common "cat or a dog" classification scenario. It's closer to facial recognition (recognize a distinct/unique object).
The problem I am trying to solve is "product recognition". I would train the system using product images from a large catalogue of 100,000+ distinct products and then given an image or video feed have it segment products it identifies. In this system I don't want the inference to tell me the class (ie, "it's a DVD" or "it's a toy") - I want it to know exactly which product (ie, one-to-one match to a UPC) and highlight it onscreen. This isn't a barcode scanner though, I still need it to recognise the product from visual cues without requiring a barcode or specific text. The product might also be on an angle or partially obscured. Ideally looking for something that runs accelerated on mobile devices (Android), in near-realtime.
Scale and rotation invariance is important. Also the products will often be closely packed (ie a bookshelf or basket of toys).
I don't know if ML is the right tool for this. I am leaning towards just using OpenCV to do feature extraction and match based on the number of matching features but I don't know how well this will scale since most of the systems I've seen are brute force KNN matching. If I use ML I don't know which types of algorithms support large numbers of classes/objects. I could also look at facial recognition techniques but most examples I've seen discuss haars cascades for faces only and I'm not sure what's involved in building a dataset for other types of objects without common features.
Anyway, hopefully that's enough to get recommendations on techniques/algorithms I can start experimenting with (or should immediately rule out).

SpliFF. For your task, a combination of traditional and ML-based approaches could work well. Here are my opinions.
Feature Matching with OpenCV:
Start with OpenCV’s feature detectors (e.g., ORB, SIFT) for feature extraction and matching. Use FLANN-based matching to scale better with a large catalog. However, this might struggle with scaling to 100k+ products.
Deep Learning:
Consider using a deep metric learning approach like Siamese Networks or Triplet Loss, which can learn embeddings for each product. This approach is more scalable as it avoids a classification bottleneck. You'd train the network to generate unique embeddings for each product, then compare embeddings during inference.
Object Detection and Segmentation:
Use a pre-trained model like Mask R-CNN for object segmentation. Fine-tune it on your dataset to improve its ability to highlight products in cluttered environments.
Real-time Mobile Inference:
To deploy on mobile, export models to frameworks like TensorFlow Lite or ONNX, and use hardware acceleration (e.g., GPU or NNAPI on Android).
This hybrid approach—using deep embeddings for product recognition and detection models for segmentation—should be scalable and robust, especially when products are tightly packed or rotated. I hope this answer could help you.
